# PsychoPy Builder - How to I take a rest part way through a set of trials?

Tags: psychopy

In PsychoPy builder, I have a lot of trials and I want to let the participant take a rest/break part way through and then press SPACE to continue when they're ready.

Any suggestions about how best to do this?

Answer (score 3):

PsychoPy Builder uses the `TrialHandler` class and you can make use of its attributes to do control when you want to take a rest.

Assuming you're trial loop is utilising an Excel/csv file to get the trial data then make use of `trialHandler`'s attribute : `thisTrialN`

e.g.

1/ Add a routine containing a text component into your loop (probably at the beginning)    with your 'now take a rest...' message and a keyboard component to    take the response when they are ready to continue.

2/ Add a custom code component as well and place something similar to this code into its "Begin Routine" tab:

```
if trials.thisTrialN  not in [ int(trials.nTotal / 2) ]:
    continueRoutine=False
```

where 'trials' is the 'name' of your trial loop.

The above will put a rest in the middle of the current set of trials but you could replace it with something like this

```
if trials.thisTrialN  not in [10,20]:
    continueRoutine=False
```

if you wanted to stop after 10 and again after 20 trials.

Note, if you're NOT using an Excel file but are simply using the 'repeat' feature of a simple trial loop, then you'll need to replace `thisTrialN`   with `thisRepN`

If you're using an Excel file AND reps you'll need to factor in both when working out when you want to rest.

This works by using one of Builder's own variables - `continueRoutine` and sets it false for most trials so that most of the time it doesn't display the 'take a rest' message.

If you want to understand more, then use the 'compile script' button (or F5) and take a look at the python code that Builder generates for you.

Comment: A [user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5103237/korey-macdougall) tried to comment with the following: "l Just wanted to add that the above solution only worked for me when I put the code into the "Each Frame" tab of the custom code snippet. It wasn't working in the begin routine tab."

Comment: Agreed, such code (currently) won't have any effect when placed in the "begin routine" tab, and needs to be placed in the "Every frame" tab. This certainly is not ideal, and I've noted it here as an issue: https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy/issues/1143